# C# Regex Replace string with Ignore specific word

Tags: regex, biztalk

I have File and I want to replace fix character `* : ~ with @` using regex but, it should not replace(ignore) `B~~` word because, it need to remain as it is. Anybody have idea for that?

**Input :**

```
ABCHKLJNKL*dskjnsdfkdsmflkmdls
MLKMLKMLKMLKMLKMMML
zlmlkmm:skjnjnskfjnkjsdnkfjnkdjs
B~~KJNNKJNJNKKJNKJNFKKJNJNK
```

**Output Should be :**

```
ABCHKLJNKL@dskjnsdfkdsmflkmdls
MLKMLKMLKMLKMLKMMML
zlmlkmm@skjnjnskfjnkjsdnkfjnkdjs
B~~KJNNKJNJNKKJNKJNFKKJNJNK
```

Please provide regex because i want to done with one step.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far? You want us to do the work for you?

Comment: What's the output if the input is `B~fooo`, `f~~fhjf`, `B~B` ?

Comment: Hi,Avinash..answer should be for B~fooo to B@fooo , f~~fhjf to f@@fhjf,B~B to B@B. we need to ignore when we get B~~ in file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[*:]|(?<!B[~])[~](?![~])
```

Try this.This should do it.See demo.Replace by `@`.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/66

Comment: Thanks Vks. Great Anwser and its work for me.